# Reading a configuration file from azure function with precompiled assembly

Tags: azure

I've an Azure Function that should read data from a file called schema.config
I've uploaded it on the portal as shown here
[image]

In my application I do

```
  public static string GetSchemaFile()
  {
        string file = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("schemafile");

        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);

        return fi.FullName;

  }
```

And I've defined an application setting on Azure as
[image]

When I run the code I got this exception

> Exception while executing function: Functions.blobfunction
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException : Exception while executing function: Functions.blobfunction ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException : Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Windows\system32\bin\schema.json'.

So it seems that it looks in D:\Windows\System32 as working folder...
How do I tell to look the file in the "bin" folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the Kudu console you can see your exact folder structure. Here's how to do that:

1. Click on your function app root node in Azure Portal (the one right below where it says "Function Apps" in the top left)
2. Click on "Platform Features" at the top
3. Click on "Advanced Tools (Kudu)" under "Development Tools" on the left hand side, this opens a new window/tab
4. Select CMD at the top under "Debug Console"
5. Navigate to site/wwwroot and you'll see all your projects
6. Select your project then the bin directory

The actual full path will then be displayed in the bottom part of the window, you can use that instead.

You may want to consider renaming the folder to something other than bin, traditionally that's where you put executable files.